# Convert Date to String using simpledateformat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm having issues when converting a date to string in a different format. The date:

```
lastDownloadDate>>Wed Feb 27 16:20:23 IST 2013
lastChangeDate>>Wed Feb 27 15:11:00 IST 2013
```

I want to convert this format to another format: `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`.

When I try to convert it I'm getting different results using:

```
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");


String lastDownloadTimeVal = outputFormat.format(lastDownloadDate);
System.out.println("lastDownloadTimeVal>>"+lastDownloadTimeVal);
String lastChangeTimeVal = outputFormat.format(lastChangeDate);
System.out.println("lastChangeTimeVal>>"+lastChangeTimeVal);
```

I'm getting the wrong result, the month is being replaced with minutes:

```
lastDownloadTimeVal>>2013-20-27 16:20:23
lastChangeTimeVal>>2013-11-27 15:11:00
```

Comment: Month pattern is MM not mm

Comment: @MiguelPrz the only one to explain why OP should use M instead of m for month. +1. I have given only you an upvote if it was an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss` this is wrong. This should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.
Refer this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for more details regarding converting date from one format to another.

Comment: it was my typo issue. instead of MM i used mm in the code in hurry. :(

Comment: @user2057006 It is not a big mistake.

Comment: We've all done the same mistake at some time :) btw, would u consider marking Apurv's answer as Solved?

Answer (score 1):

You have used wrong format for month.

```
yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss ----> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
mm--->Minutes. 
MM--->Months
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

to

```
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
mm for Minutes
MM for Months
```